# Passin Parameters from Filter to Business Service in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have 3 REST services which are reading some common header parameters on the request. I need to use that parameters on my business services. instead of reading that common header parameters on each web service controller (`@RestController`), Is it possible to read that headers on request filter and make it available on the business services ? If yes, are there any examples to do this ?

Comment: Give example of what you need, just read/write headers in RestController and filter ?

Comment: @user7294900 - I mean reading the request headers on Filter and access that parameters on a business service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Nitin suggest you can pass the request object from your controllers to your services and read the header there. There is no problem with that.

If you still want to read it in a filter and have it available in any @Service you can do as follows:

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class HeaderReaderFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    private HeaderDataHolder headerDataHolder;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        headerDataHolder.setHeaderContent(httpRequest.getHeader("header_field"));
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

@RequestScope
@Component
public class HeaderDataHolder {

    private String headerContent;

    public String getHeaderContent() {
        return headerContent;
    }

    public void setHeaderContent(String headerContent) {
        this.headerContent = headerContent;
    }
}
```

And then have the `HeaderDataHolder` `@Autowired` in your service classes. Notice the necessary `@RequestScope` so you have a different bean for each request.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tested Nitin Zadage's answer and it is working fine without Filter. But what I want is, avoid reading the HttpServletRequest objects inside my services class. That is why I thought to read that on Filter class. Now I am going to try your answer. Do I need to add ```@RequestScope``` on my service class ?

Comment: No, you only need `@RequestScope`on the `HeaderDataHolder` class

Comment: I have implemented this solution in my REST services. Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 1):

You can get request object

```java
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

and access the headers in business services using request object.

Comment: So is it not required to read that parameters on Filter first ? Can access headers on business service class (class with ```@Service```) straightaway ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tested your answer and it is working fine without Filter. But what I want is, avoid reading the HttpServletRequest objects inside my services class. That is why I thought to read that on Filter class.

Comment: Headers are request specific and RequestContextHolder is designed to give you hold of request specific attributes in that thread rather than passing request or request specific objects in the stack. I don't see any meaning assigning headers to any other variable and pass them through the stack to business service.